# Como fazer um ComboBox com GridView?

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox

Estou tentando fazer um ComboBox que ai clicar seja preenchido com uma GridView, sei que é do DevExpress, hoje utilizo a versão 16.1.

exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, poderia ser mais especifico?

Comment: Como você pretende adicionar valores da GridView no combo box? Quais são os campos? Como esta a sua rotina responsável?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chama-se GridLookUpEdit.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode-se encapsular um `gridview` em um `combobox`.